# get server time stamp in sql format

Tags: php, postgresql

How would one get the server timestamp in the same format that it is stored in postgresql database? I'm trying to figure the time difference between the server time and the one stored on one of the rows in the database?

Answer (score 1):

`current_timestamp` gives the start time of the transaction. The time is that of the server.

```
SELECT my_time, current_timestamp
FROM my_table;
```